# PHP Script to add a user to mailing list in cPanel?

Tags: php, mailing-list

I've a mailing list in my cPanel. When a user registers, I want to add him to my mailing list automatically. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, cPanel uses [Mailman](http://www.gnu.org/software/mailman/index.html) for mailing lists. This means you can probably do something like this to add an email to a mailing list:

```
shell_exec("echo user@example.com | /var/lib/mailman/bin/add_members -r - LISTNAME");
```

where LISTNAME is the name of the mailing list. Depending on your system, the path to the Mailman scripts may be somewhere other than /var/lib/mailman/bin/.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what mailing list you're using. I'm not too familiar with what cPanel uses for lists.

In the past, I have used cUrl to add databases and users via requests to specifically constructed urls within the appropriate parts of cPanel.

Answer (score 0):

The cPanel instances that I've seen use Mailman.

There's a PEAR package which provides a PHP API to Mailman:
http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.webservices.services-mailman.php